# How to make a transparent ContinueWith callback which forwards the task completion information?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I'm having a `Task` with a `ContinueWith` callback. However this is in a separate function which returns the `Task`, so the caller can optionally add more `ContinueWith` callbacks or do whatever he wants. I need a way to make this first `ContinueWith` callback transparent, so that it passes forward the result (not hard) and also the `Exception` property (this seems to be harder).

If I rethrow the exception I have an issue if the caller doesn't add another `ContinueWith` callback which would handle it, and it will fall out unhandled to the outer space which I want to avoid.

On the other hand, I don't know how elso I could add the existing `Exception` to the current task without throwing it.

Here is some sample code.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  throw new Exception("test");
}).ContinueWith(t => {
  // this is my general handler
  MyExceptionHandler.Handle(t.Exception);
  // etc...
  // HERE set the Exception for the current task to forward it
  return t.Result; // result forwarded
}).ContinueWith(t => {
  // this MIGHT be appended by consumer code
  if (t.Exception) // HERE I would like to see the exception which might have been thrown be the original task.
  // do whatever ...
});
```

**UPDATE**

I've actually noticed that the `Exception` does get propagated, but it gets rewrapped into a new `AggregateException`.

Comment: What do you mean by unhandled? That it didn't pass through `MyExceptionHandler.Handle`? Or that the task will raise the `UnobservedTaskException` event?

Comment: No, it would pass though it. I ment if I rethrow the `t.Exception` afterwards. But according to my last tests it doesn't really matter, I wasn't aware of the exact behavior. See my update.

Comment: I saw the update, that's why I asked. You want to use `t.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `t.Result`. It wouldn't wrap the exception in an `AggregateException`. Keep in mind though that unless the consumer added another continuation the continuation you added will create a task with an unhandled exception.

Comment: Yes this is the problem. I'm gonna use the approach you provided in your answer, thank you. It will be fine, even if order is indeterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe can't be done. To let the exception flow through your continuation you need to throw it.

What you *can do* however is add multiple continuations on the same task instead of chaining them. The first makes sure the exception gets handled and the others may use the result (or the exception):

```
Task task = ...
task.ContinueWith(
    _ => MyExceptionHandler.Handle(_.Exception),
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
task.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    if (_.Exception)
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the execution order deterministic here?

Comment: I need that common `ContinueWith` handler in both success and failure cases (actually in any case, including cancel as well). Is the execution order defined in this case? I can't find any documentation currently on this.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, as I realized that execution order doesn't matter in my case (I'm doing kind of a logging in the general continuation).Thank you.